# Using AttachConsole, while the process I've attached with is running and spewing, I can still type and run other commands

Tags: c#, .net, console, console-application

Using AttachConsole, while the process I've attached with is running and spewing, I can still type and run other commands.

My program runs in either a form, or from command line. If started with arguments it runs in the command window. I use AttachConsole(-1) to attach my process to command window I called from.
It works great, I get all my output spew from my process.

However, the console still processes user input from the keyboard, whatever I type, for instance, if I type 'cls' and hit enter, the output will be wiped. How can I block user input to the console while the process is running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not be elegant based on what you are doing, but do a Kill() on the console after attaching it and it will continue to get output from your other process. Example Windows Forms code below, add your own bells and whistles:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
   internal static class Program
    {
    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);

    [STAThread]
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr ptr = GetForegroundWindow();

        int u;

        GetWindowThreadProcessId(ptr, out u);

        Process process = Process.GetProcessById(u);

        AttachConsole(process.Id);

        process.Kill();

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();

        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I stumbled on this when searching for a way to attach a console to a WinForms app. When I tested this code, the VS2022 was killed. That happened because the code gets for the foreground window process, and then kills this process. As there was no window from the application... the VS was murdered.

Answer (score 3):

I found a little cleaner solution is just to send an extra "Enter" to the console after your program exits:

```
[STAThread]
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
        ...
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception eCatchAll)
    {
        ShowHelpCommand.ShowHelp(eCatchAll.ToString());     
        return (int) ConsoleReturnCode.UnexpectedError;
    }
    finally
    {
        ConsoleNewLine();
    }
}

private static void ConsoleNewLine()
{
    try
    {
        // When using a winforms app with AttachConsole the app complets but there is no newline after the process stops. This gives the newline and looks normal from the console:
        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Fail(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about this but is AllocConsole instead of AttachConsole not a more easy approach for this problem?