# read input of hand opened console application

Tags: c#, process

I have a form application that starts a console application. I don't have acces to the code of both applications. Now I want to read the output of the console application into my own application. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: "I don't have access to the code of both applications" -- do you mean you have the code for _neither_ of the applications? Or you have code for one but not the other? Where does "my own application" fit in here? Is that the Winforms program? Or a _third_ program that you want to use to intercept the interaction between the first two? There is a lot missing from this question.

Comment: You must use WINApi and call AttachConsole command. See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629393/using-attachconsole-while-the-process-ive-attached-with-is-running-and-spewing][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629393/using-attachconsole-while-the-process-ive-attached-with-is-running-and-spewing