# Using istream (std cin): prevent "[input] is not recognized as ..." on Windows

Tags: c++, cmd, cin

I have a Qt gui application with commandline functionality.
To make this work I added this to the top of the `main()` function:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
if (AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)) {
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
}
#endif
```

Then an instance of my main class is constructed. In the constructor, `QCommandLineParser` determines if there are any arguments, and either creates an instance of the cmdline parsing class, or the gui application class.

In the cmdline parsing class, I ask the user to input certain values:

```
QString qanswer;

// `answerToInt` is an std::unordered_map
while (answerToInt.find(qanswer) == answerToInt.end()) {
    std::cout << std::endl << "File will be overwritten:" << std::endl
              << path.toStdString() << std::endl
              << "Are you sure? " << (multiple ? "(Yes/YesAll/No/NoAll)" : "(Yes/No)") << std::endl;

    std::string answer;
    std::cin >> answer;
    qanswer = QString::fromStdString(answer).toLower();
    std::cin.clear();
}
```

When "Yes" "No", "YesAll" or "NoAll" (case insensitive) is input, the program continues as expected, but when the user inputs something other than that, cmd throws this:

> '[input]' is not recognized as an internal or external command [...]

And then the "C:\path\to\exe>" is displayed again, where the user can continue to input until one of the correct values is typed.
Once a valid string is input, it continues again as expected.

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864560/1136512) as well as `std::getline()`, but it makes no difference.

So how do I prevent the error from showing up and continue displaying the `cout`?

Comment: This looks like QString isn't able to parse `answer` from a glance. Headed into an appointment though, couldn't read too far into it. I'd start there, and include your inputs and expected outputs in the question

Comment: I edited the question a bit, hope it's clearer now. When a valid value is input it works correctly as expected, so I don't think it's a problem with QString.
I suspect it's because it's a GUI application, where normal cmd functionality doesn't work, and `freopen`s aren't enough to enable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AttachConsole` just attaches to the parent process's console, it does not stop the parent process from also reading from it. So the console input is being interleaved between the parent process (`cmd.exe`) and your app, which can be problematic to manage (some people advice [killing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629393/using-attachconsole-while-the-process-ive-attached-with-is-running-and-spewing) the parent process, which obviously isn't a good idea).

What you can do instead is to always create a *new* console (see [`AllocConsole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole)).

Or if you want to re-use the *same* console, it might be an idea to target the Console subsystem instead (linker option `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`) and have a regular `main()` function instead of `WinMain` (yes you can create Win32 windows *and* handle console I/O all within `main()`).

You can even have a multi-subsystem source that can be linked as Windows as well as Console subsystem with a shim like this (`nCmdShow` and command-line arguments remain to be implemented):

```
HWND hwnd;

int main() {
    std::thread t([] {
        // let GUI run in its own thread ...
        WinMain(GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, "", SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
        exit(0);
    });
    // meanwhile in this thread we handle console I/O ...
    std::string s;
    std::cout << "Press Enter to exit" << std::endl;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, s)) {
        if (s == "")
            break;
        std::cout << "Hello " << s << std::endl;
    }
    PostMessageA(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
    t.join();
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
     // Your normal WinMain.
     // CreateWindow, GetMessage loop etc. . .
```

Comment: Using `AllocConsole` seems like the best solution here. Is there a way to close the first console window?

Comment: Windows users typically don't start programs from the console. You could check if the parent is `cmd.exe` and kill it... Personally though I would prefer if my console remained open. Some projects ship two executables - `foo.exe` for GUI and `fooc.exe` for console mode, so that the user can choose which one they want.

Comment: I suppose you're right, the user might not want the console to close. I considered splitting it into two .exe, but I prefer to keep them unified for now. Thanks for the help!